# How to Allow for document.getElementById to Not Find an ID?

Tags: javascript

I have an external JavaScript designed to replace certain words on my website. To keep it efficient the same external script is loaded to every page so I can simply edit a single file if I need to make any changes. This is a sample of the code I'm using:

```
document.getElementById("ey").innerHTML = 'AY'
document.getElementById("ny").innerHTML = 'BY'
document.getElementById("gy").innerHTML = 'CY'
```

However, I've discovered that if one page contains one element (say, "gy") but not another ("ny"), then the script fails to correctly execute. I have a long list of these changes (50ish), so I'd love to get it working.

Any idea how I can make the code provide allowances for not finding a particular id?

Comment: don't set properties or call functions on things that might not exist. Check if they exist, then call if they do or skip if they don't. Otherwise, your script does something illegal, and its run is terminated, no matter how much perfectly fine code followed the bad line.

Comment: @LilligantEX What are the different types of elements on page that needs change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setInnerHTML('ey', 'AY');
setInnerHTML('ny', 'BY');

...etc etc

function setInnerHTML(elementId, innerHTML) {
    var el = document.getElementById(elementId);

    if (el) {
        el.innerHTML = innerHTML;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

well, you can write something like

```
var el = document.getElementById("MY-ID")
if (el)
  el.innerHTML = 'MY VALUE'
```

A nice solution is to wrap this in a method, like this:

```
function setValue(id, value){
  var el = document.getElementById(id)
  if (el)
    el.innerHTML = value
}
```

And then call it like:

```
setValue('ey', 'AY')
setValue('ny', 'BY')
```

and so on

Comment: A great answer too. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could always make a small structure for this.

```
(function(){
    var defaultChanges = {
        'ey' : 'AY',
        'ny': 'BY',
        'gy' : 'CY'
    };
    for(var id in defaultChanges){
        var el = document.querySelector("#"+id);
        if(el) el.innerHTML = defaultChanges[id];
    }
})()
```

This way going forward all you need to do is change your object, and the entire set will be changed in the page.

Comment: I like this better than my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If not found, use a dummy object:

```
(document.getElementById("ey") || {innerHTML:''}).innerHTML = 'AY' 
(document.getElementById("ny") || {innerHTML:''}).innerHTML = 'BY'
(document.getElementById("gy") || {innerHTML:''}).innerHTML = 'CY'
```